# First time using Mysqli, how to check if All connections are properly closed?

Tags: php, mysqli

Is there a way to test if all connections are properly closed?

```
<?php

$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "myuse", "mypass", "myss");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$user = $_POST['user'];
$http = $_POST['pass'];

$results = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM siri");

if (mysqli_num_rows($results) > 0) {
} else {
    mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO taible(user,http) VALUES('$user', '$http')");
    mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO mainble(user,http) VALUES('$user', '$http')");
}

mysqli_close($con);
```

Am I required to close `$results`?

Answer (score 2):

You have only one connection.
You don't have to check if it closed.
You aren't required to close $results either.

What should be your *real* concern instead is use of prepared statements.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if a connection is open with `mysqli_ping()`

Example:

```
if(mysqli_ping($con)){
    //do stuff if it is open
}
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.ping.php

And so just do that for each connection you have to check if any are open.

However, most people agree, you don't need to close the connection. It is automatically dumped when the script ends, and you are more likely to have errors and add stress to the db by opening and closing connections.